# Copy files recursively with directory structure from source server to Target server

Tags: server, sftp, copy, scp, directory-structure

I am trying to copy the files modified from specific date to current date from Source server to target server with same directory structure.
I have created the script for copying files from Source directory to target directory in same server. Now looking for 2 different Linux servers.

Source server: Source34.abc.net

Directory and files: /home/Amal/db/tmp/File1.txt, /home/Amal/db/work/File2.txt, /home/Amal/db/out.xml

Target Server: Target30.efg.net

Directory : /home/Amal/db/tmp/
/home/Amal/db/work/

Want to achieve:

1. Sftp from source server to Target server
2. Copy the files from source to Target with the same folder structure

NOTE: Source and Target will have same Directory structure

Comment: Do you only have `sftp` access to both servers? This could be easily accomplished with `ssh` access to both.

Comment: @Jos - Yes we do have the SSH permissions as well.

Comment: Try `rsync` as explained here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/183504/how-to-rsync-files-between-two-remotes/183516

Comment: I would anytime choose ssh over sftp. The command you should be looking at is ```scp```

Comment: @Jos - rsync is not available in our Linux servers. I am trying to connect to source server, Find the files modified or created between 2 dates, And then copy into Target server with the same directory structure.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the most easiest way to use `scp` through ssh.

Open terminal in source system and type in the command below

`scp <source-directory> -i <path-to-ssh-key> <ipaddress-of-target>@<user>:<target-directory>`